# TYPO3 doesn't show any pages in submenu

Tags: typo3

In my TYPO3 I have this code for submenu

```
lib.subnav = COA
lib.subnav {
    wrap = <ul class="nav nav-list" id="sidebar-nav">|</ul>

    10 = TEXT
    10.wrap = <li class="list-group-item">|</li>
    #10.wrap {
    #    override = <li class="list-group-item current">|</li>
    #    override.if {
    #        value.data = field:uid
    #        equals.data = leveluid:1
    #    }
    #}
    10.data = leveltitle:1
    #10.data =  levelfield:1,nav_title // leveltitle:1
    10.typolink.parameter.data = leveluid:1

    20 = HMENU
    20.wrap = |
    20 {
        entryLevel = 1
        1 = TMENU
        1 {
            wrap = |
            expAll = 0

            NO = 1
            NO.allWrap >
            NO.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="list-group-item">|</li>
            CUR = 1
            CUR < .NO
            CUR.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="list-group-item active current">|</li>
            ACT = 1
            ACT < .CUR
            ACT.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="list-group-item active">|</li>

            # Dropdown menu
            IFSUB = 1
            IFSUB < .NO
            IFSUB.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="list-group-item">|</li>
            IFSUB.ATagBeforeWrap = 1
            IFSUB.stdWrap.wrap = |

            CURIFSUB = 1
            CURIFSUB < .IFSUB
            CURIFSUB.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="list-group-item active current">|</li>

            ACTIFSUB = 1
            ACTIFSUB < .IFSUB
            ACTIFSUB.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="list-group-item active">|</li>
        }


        2 = TMENU
        2 {
            wrap = <ul class="list-group">|</ul>
            expAll = 0

            NO = 1
            NO.allWrap >
            NO.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="list-group-item">|</li>
            ACT = 1
            ACT < .NO
            ACT.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="list-group-item active">|</li>
            CUR = 1
            CUR < .ACT
            CUR.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="list-group-item active current">|</li>

            IFUSB < .1.IFSUB
            ACTIFSUB < .1.ACTIFSUB
            CURIFSUB < .1.CURIFSUB

            SPC = 1
            SPC.doNotLinkIt = 1
            SPC.doNotShowLink = 1
            SPC.allWrap = <li class="divider"></li>
        }

        3 < .2
        # no submenus anymore
        3.IFSUB >
        3.ACTIFSUB >
    }
}
```

If I wiev the source of the page I can se this line: | but no menu items.
I have tried to chage submenu.entrylevel, but nothing changes.
There a subpages, so that is not the problem.

It is TYPO3 8.7 and I know that it is terrible old, but I need this to work before an update.

Comment: you can adjust `expAll = 1` or each menu

Comment: I'd do the upgrade now and fix it afterwards. In a newer version you have the possibility that some bugs are fixed and you also have the possibility to do this menu with a data processor in an easier way.

Comment: Can we please stop bashing TypoScript menus? Fluid/DataProcessors won't do anything here, because you also need to understand `entryLevel` and `expAll`. That's the key.

Answer (score 1):

Let's have an example page:

- Home/Root

  - Page 1

    - Page 1.1

      - Page 1.1.1
    - Page 1.2
  - Page 2
  - Page 3

    - Page 3.1
    - Page 3.2

      - Page 3.2.1

---

Regarding `entryLevel`:

Default is "0" which gives us a menu of the very first pages on the site. For the tree above, the menu will contain "Page 1", "Page 2", "Page 3".

`entryLevel=1` will show the pages below. So, if you are on "Page 1", the menu will show "Page 1.1." and "Page 1.2" (active rootline). On "Page 2" the menu will not show up anything, because there are no pages below Page 2. On "Home/Root" no menu will appear because there's no level 1 directly underneath.

---

`expAll`

If this is true, the menu will always show the menu on the level underneath the menu item.

Back to the pagetree: having `entryLevel=0` and `20.1.expAll=1` *all* submenus of the third level will be expanded, not only the one of active rootline. All "Page x.x" will appear, but none of the "Page x.x.x".

For getting a full dropdown-menu, also the next level needs to be expanded: `20.2.expAll=1`

Comment: I found pages where it works. They are on level 3. But I need the menu also for some pages on level 2. Can I change the entrylevel in Typoscript on a specific page?

Comment: Found it. lib.subnav.20.entryLevel = 2